# VueJS background-image url not finding the path

Tags: css, vue.js, url, background-image, vue-cli

i am learning VueJs and i'm blocked.
My problem is that i don't know which path i need to give to the url of my background-image property on the component css part.

```
<template>
  <div class="layer"></div>
<template>

<script>
 export default {
   name: 'Layer'
 }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.layer{
  background-image: url(../public/images/myImage.jpg)
}
</style>
```

What url do i need to put?
My image is on 'public/images/myImage.jpg'
My component Layer is on 'src/components/Layer.vue'

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if your img is on public, just write as relative path:

```
.layer{
  background-image: url('/images/myImage.jpg')
}
```